# How do typical ground marshaling signals differ for helicopters?

Tags: helicopter, ground-operations

There are common hand signals used by ground crew for fixed wing aircraft like 'taxi forward', 'spin up engine #1', 'turn right', or **'stop'**, for example:

[image]

At most airports, general helicopter traffic doesn't *need* to be marshaled, but I'm sure that pilots must be required to at least know some standard signals, in case of some communication issue that would require the use of hand signals.

Do these signals differ for helicopters, and how so? Do helicopter pilots have a different set of signals they must know?

Answer (score 5):

All of the signals used for marshaling fixed wing aircraft apply to rotary wing aircraft as well.

There are additional signals though related to hover maneuvers such as move left or right, hover left or right, forwards, etc.
and land (or rather cleared to land), take off into the hover, etc.

Marshaling large helicopters can be very difficult, especially in dust and snow conditions.

Source: ex. 7 Sqn Chinooks